# ¿Cómo imprimir saltos de línea?

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de hacer saltos de línea mediante la conocida secuencia de escape `"\n"` y no consigo que imprima el salto de línea.

Por ejemplo, si tengo el siguiente código:

```
$var = "Soy Alberto";
$foo = "Que tal\n, como estas";

echo "$var\n";
echo "$foo";
```

Me lo imprime todo en la misma línea. He estado buscando por todo google pero la única solución que dan es usar la etiqueta de html `<br>`.

Answer (score 4):

Sí funciona. El tema es que un salto de línea en un html no se muestra en la página.

Por definición, en html uno o más espacios en  blanco (espacio, tab, salto de línea, salto de página) son procesados como un único espacio.

Así se ve un html con varios espacios en blanco entre cada palabra (hacer click en Ejecutar):

```html
<body>
    No
    se
    imprime
</body>
```

Para ver los saltos de línea y otros espacios, podés:

1. Ver el código fuente de la página (click derecho, ver código fuente).
2. Imprimiendo dentro de una etiqueta `<pre>`.

   ```
   echo "<body>\n<pre>Ahora\nsí\n</pre>\n</body>";
   ```

   Así se ve:

   ```html
   <body>
   <pre>Ahora
   sí
   </pre>
   </body>
   ```
3. O cambiar el `"\n"` por [`"<br>"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/br) (y te puede ser útil la función [**`nl2br()`**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php))

   ```
   echo "$var<br>$foo";
   ```

Comment: Esta es la respuesta correcta. Imagina que estás editando una página HTML y estás indentando correctamente. Un salto de línea entre un `<div>` y sus elementos hijos generaría saltos de línea en el documento mostrado en el browser. Eso sería muy inconveniente.

Comment: Es que estoy siguiendo varios manuales y tutoriales y a todos les imprime en pantalla del navegador el salto de línea...

Comment: @Jogofus Así procesa un html tu navegador. Está definido de esa forma en el lenguaje. Probablemente el tutorial haya simplificado un poco para ir cubriendo de a un tema por vez.

Answer (score 3):

Para los saltos de línea "visibles" en un documento HTML se usa el tag **`<br>`**.

Para imprimir saltos de línea en un fichero utiliza la constante **PHP_EOL** que imprime un salto de línea con independencia del SO donde se ejecute la aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Proba asi:

```
$var = "Soy Alberto";
$foo = "Que tal, como estas";

echo "$var<br>";
echo "$foo";
```

O asi:

```
$foo = 'Soy Alberto'; 
echo nl2br("Hello \n $foo!");
```

Comment: Así debería funcionar, pero por qué no funciona el salto se línea estándar?

Comment: Son problemas del `format` parametro. Si tenes ganas lo podes leer mas detallado aca http://php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php En mi respuesta te edite otra forma de hacer salto de linea.

Comment: No dice nada referente a esto...

Comment: El salto de línea que intentas imprimir. Lo imprime en resultado del script. El cual es el código HTML. Pero los navegadores. No interpretan los saltos de línea a menos que sean tags. Sin embargo si se imprimen en el código fuente resultante de tu script. Si deseas ver los saltos de línea que estás imprimiendo revisa el código fuente. O ejecuta tu script con cli.